# Cannot apply CSS filter property in IE10

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, css-filters

I need to apply CSS filter on `body` tag. Now I use this CSS rules - 
[JS fiddle with CSS styles](https://jsfiddle.net/vdy3wsxg/)

In Chrome, FF, Opera it works fine. But in IE 10 it doesn't applying.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert filter not working on IE and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997521/invert-filter-not-working-on-ie-and-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support `filter` properties. Wait for the release of Microsoft Edge, it will support `filter`

Comment: I do not believe Edge will support it either.

Comment: It doesn't support by default but can be enabled

Comment: Supported as of now-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn965466(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There is no indication that it will be available for wide use in Edge. If it's behind a flag, then users won't use it so it's as if it's not there at all.

Comment: @Sidsec9 okay, but how can I achieve same effect in IE? SVG?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot achieve the same in IE as of now.

Comment: @Sidsec9 yes, I've seen this, but can't find any good tutorial about svg filtering

Comment: This is a good place to begin with SVG - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything wrong. CSS filters don't work in IE and [won't in the foreseeable future](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter).

Comment: There is no indication that it **won't** be available for wide use in Edge.

Comment: @Sidsec9 Never, ever trust Microsoft to do the right thing. If you want to respond to my comments, do so under my comments in your answer, not mine.